# ConnectionString is null on IIS 7.5 but not IIS 8 with Asp.net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2

I'm sure I'm horribly misconstruing this issue but in summary.  I have a tiny Web API app that works as expected on a Server running IIS 8 but on IIS 7.5 the Connection String is always null.

Here are the moving parts.  Again, this works from a different server and my local machine.

### Controller

```
public class InfrastructureController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IInfrastructureService _infrastructureService;

    public InfrastructureController(IInfrastructureService infrastructureService)
    {
        _infrastructureService = infrastructureService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Status check endpoint to receive basic information about the API.
    /// </summary>
    [Route("status")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult StatusCheck()
    {
        var status = new
        {
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
            DatabaseConnected = _infrastructureService.IsDatabaseConnected()
        };

        return Ok(status);
    }
}
```

### Service

```
public class InfrastructureService : IInfrastructureService
{
    public bool IsDatabaseConnected()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Open();
                if(db.Database.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### web.config

```
<configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyAppDB"
           connectionString="Server=myAppServer;Database=MyApp;User ID=MyUserId;Password=MyPwd;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
      <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
        <namespace name="MyApp.APICore.Authentication" />
        <assembly name="MyApp.APICore" />

        <container>
          <register type="IMyAppProvider" mapTo="DummyAuthenticationProvider" />
        </container>
      </unity>
    </configuration>
```

### DBContext

```
class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    public MyAppContext() : base("MyAppDB")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, but where is the connection string supposed to come from? You did not display this part

Comment: have you compared the  setting in the working IIS vs the non working in IIS 7.5 if the code works on one.. I doubt that it's a code issue sounds like a setting issue

Comment: @Andrei sorry, didn't think that was relevant.  The connectionString is in the `web.config`

Comment: @MethodMan yeah I did and I worried about that, posting here on SO.  Is there a more appropriate place I should be looking for help?

Comment: this posting here is fine.. however I think it would make more sense to show how you are getting the connection string.. have you checked the project to see what the settings are in regards to what web server is pointing to ..?

Comment: Where the connection string is stored and how it is retrieved is most relevant here, as web.config file was getting updates along with IIS versions, so you might be using something IIS 8 specific. Anyway, please post relevant part of the web.config (including the enclosing sections, not just the connectionString node) and the way you read it in the code

Comment: Fair enough, I added the web.config and the DBContext that references the ConnectionString.  As for where it's stored, I might be misunderstanding but this is a REALLY small app, you've seen all the functionality, and so the web.config is stored in the root folder of the web app.